# long table landscape with two columns

Tags: tables, landscape

```
How to delete the column "WOMEN" from this table. i need to keep only two column 

 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
 \usepackage{graphicx,color,psfrag}
  \usepackage{epstopdf}
      \usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{breakurl}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
 \usepackage{blindtext}


 \usepackage{newpxtext}

  % caption fonts
 \usepackage[font={large,bf}]{caption} 

 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{threeparttable}  
 \usepackage{tabulary}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{float}
 \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}


  \begin{document}



 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{center}
     \caption{Main effects of 1966 FLSA on white-black elasticity of substitution}
    \label{tab:table_llsubstitution_cps}
    \resizebox{!}{0.37\textheight}{

 \begin{tabular}{lccccccccc}

      \toprule
       \toprule
      & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Baseline cross-state design}} & \multicolumn{ 3}{c} 
  {\textbf{Alternative design \#1}}  & \multicolumn{ 3}{c}{\textbf{Alternative design \#2}}\\
   & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Strongly vs. weakly treated states} & \multicolumn{ 3}{c}{Kaitz index}  & \multicolumn{ 3}{c}{Fraction of affected workers}\\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
    \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    \cmidrule(lr){8-10}
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{All}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Men}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{All}&\multicolumn{1} 
  {c}{Men}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{All}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Men}&\\
     \cmidrule{2-10}
  Treatment var. $\times$& & & \\ \hspace{0.5cm}{1967-1972}&               &               &               &               &               &               &               &               &               \\
    \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textbf{Relative W/B shares of workers}&       0.010** &       0.010*   &               &               &               &               &               &               \\
                &     (0.004)   &     (0.005)   &     (0.006)   &               &               &               &               &               &               \\
  time\_emp=2 $\times$ Standardized values of (KI\_1966S) &               &               &               &       0.006*  &       0.006*  &       0.006   &               &               &               \\
                &               &               &               &     (0.003)   &     (0.003)   &     (0.004)   &               &               &               \\
   time\_emp=2 $\times$ Standardized values of (F\_s1966) &               &               &               &               &               &               &       0.005***&       0.006***&       0.005   \\
                &               &               &               &               &               &               &     (0.002)   &     (0.002)   &     (0.003)   \\
      \hspace{0.2cm}{}    &     662,539   &     410,128   &     252,411   &     662,539   &     410,128   &     252,411   &     662,539   &     410,128   &     252,411   \\
    \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textbf{Relative W/B epop gap}&      -0.007   &      -0.009   &      -0.008   &               &               &               &               &               &               \\
                &     (0.011)   &     (0.015)   &     (0.019)   &               &               &               &               &               &               \\
    time\_emp=2 $\times$ white $\times$ Standardized values of (KI\_1966S) &               &               &               &       0.004   &      -0.000   &       0.009*  &               &               &               \\
                &               &               &               &     (0.004)   &     (0.007)   &     (0.005)   &               &               &               \\
 time\_emp=2 $\times$ white $\times$ Standardized values of (F\_s1966) &               &               &               &               &               &               &       0.005   &       0.003   &       0.007   \\
                &               &               &               &               &               &               &     (0.004)   &     (0.005)   &     (0.007)   \\
      \hspace{0.2cm}{}    &     944,981   &     449,200   &     495,781   &     944,981   &     449,200   &     495,781   &     944,981   &     449,200   &     495,781   \\
   \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textbf{Relative W/B earnings}&      -0.089***&      -0.091***&      -0.092***&               &               &               &               &               &               \\
                &     (0.026)   &     (0.032)   &     (0.026)   &               &               &               &               &               &               \\
       time=2 $\times$ white $\times$ Standardized values of (KI\_1966S) &               &               &               &      -0.030***&      -0.032***&      -0.029** &               &               &               \\
                &               &               &               &     (0.009)   &     (0.009)   &     (0.012)   &               &               &               \\
      time=2 $\times$ white $\times$ Standardized values of (F\_s1966) &               &               &               &               &               &               &      -0.038***&      -0.043***&      -0.033***\\
                &               &               &               &               &               &               &     (0.010)   &     (0.011)   &     (0.010)   \\
      \hspace{0.2cm}{}    &     534,977   &     336,099   &     198,878   &     534,977   &     336,099   &     198,878   &     534,977   &     336,099   &     198,878   \\
       \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textbf{L-L elast. (emp. shares)}&        0.01&        0.01&        0.01&        0.02&        0.02&        0.03&        0.02&        0.01&        0.02\\
 se                  &        0.01&        0.01&        0.01&        0.02&        0.01&        0.02&        0.01&        0.01&        0.01\\
   lower bound         &        0.00&        0.00&       -0.00&       -0.01&       -0.01&       -0.01&        0.00&        0.00&       -0.01\\
    upper bound         &        0.02&        0.02&        0.03&        0.05&        0.05&        0.06&        0.03&        0.02&        0.04\\
     \rule{0pt}{3ex}\textbf{L-L elast. (epop gap)}&        0.10&        0.08&        0.18&       -0.06&        0.01&       -0.21&       -0.08&       -0.05&       -0.07\\
      se                  &        0.12&        0.16&        0.25&        0.14&        0.19&        0.17&        0.11&        0.12&        0.24\\
    lower bound         &       -0.14&       -0.23&       -0.30&       -0.33&       -0.37&       -0.54&       -0.29&       -0.28&       -0.54\\
    upper bound         &        0.34&        0.38&        0.66&        0.22&        0.39&        0.11&        0.14&        0.18&        0.40\\
     \bottomrule

       \end{tabular}}
       \end{center}
       {\footnotesize {Source: CPS 1962-1981. \\
   Sample: For regressions on (i) share of whites among all workers and (ii) probability of being employed vs. unemployed or nor in the labor force (in order to look at white-black gap in employment-population ratio): Adults 25-55, black or white, employed, unemployed ((ii) only) or not in the labor force ((ii) only). For regression on log annual earnings: Adults 25-55, black or white, worked more than 13 weeks last year and 3 hours last week, not self-employed, not in group quarters, not unpaid family worker, no missing industry or occupation code. \\
   Notes: see notes of Table~\ref{tab:table_emp_cps_mef}. 
    }}
                      \end{table}
                        \end{landscape}
            
            
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

              \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that isn't really a tex question just use your editor to delete those entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution defines a column type named `g`, short for "gobble" and assigns this column type to 3 of the 9 data columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%%\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{graphicx}    %%%%%,color,psfrag}
%%%%%\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}
%%%%%\usepackage{breakurl}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}

% caption fonts
\usepackage[font={bf},skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} 
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{threeparttable}  
%%\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}

%% new:
\usepackage{collcell}
\makeatletter
%% 'g' for 'gobble':
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\collectcell\@gobble}c<{\endcollectcell}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{sidewaystable}[!ht]
\small
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Main effects of 1966 FLSA on white-black elasticity of substitution}
    \label{tab:table_llsubstitution_cps}

 \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{2}{wc{2.5cm}}g *{2}{*{2}{wc{2cm}}g} @{}}
\toprule
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Baseline cross-state design}}& 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Alternative design \#1}}     &
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Alternative design \#2}}\\
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Strongly vs.\ weakly treated states} &
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Kaitz index}  &
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fraction of affected workers}\\
  \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{All}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Men}&
  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{All}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Men}&
  &\multicolumn{1}{c}{All}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Men}&\\
  \cmidrule[\lightrulewidth](l){2-10}
  Treatment var. $\times$& & & \\ 
  \hspace{5mm}{1967--1972}& & & & & & & & & \\
  \addlinespace 
  \textbf{Relative W/B shares of workers}& 0.010** & 0.010* & & & & & & \\
                                         & (0.004) & (0.005) & (0.006) & & & & & & \\
  time\_emp = 2 $\times$ Standardized values of (KI\_1966S) & & & &       0.006*  &       0.006*  &       0.006   & & & \\
 & & & &     (0.003)   &     (0.003)   &     (0.004)   & & & \\
   time\_emp = 2 $\times$ Standardized values of (F\_s1966) & & & & & & &       0.005***&       0.006***&       0.005   \\
 & & & & & & &     (0.002)   &     (0.002)   &     (0.003)   \\
      &     662,539   &     410,128   &     252,411   &     662,539   &     410,128   &     252,411   &     662,539   &     410,128   &     252,411   \\
  \addlinespace 
  \textbf{Relative W/B epop gap}&      -0.007   &      -0.009   &      -0.008   & & & & & & \\
 &     (0.011)   &     (0.015)   &     (0.019)   & & & & & & \\
    time\_emp=2 $\times$ white $\times$ Standardized values of (KI\_1966S) & & & &       0.004   &      -0.000   &       0.009*  & & & \\
 & & & &     (0.004)   &     (0.007)   &     (0.005)   & & & \\
 time\_emp=2 $\times$ white $\times$ Standardized values of (F\_s1966) & & & & & & &       0.005   &       0.003   &       0.007   \\
 & & & & & & &     (0.004)   &     (0.005)   &     (0.007)   \\
      &     944,981   &  449,200   &  495,781   &  944,981   &  449,200   &  495,781   &  944,981   &  449,200   &  495,781   \\
  \addlinespace 
  \textbf{Relative W/B earnings}&  -0.089***& -0.091***& -0.092***& & & & & & \\
 &     (0.026)   &     (0.032)   &     (0.026)   & & & & & & \\
       time = 2 $\times$ white $\times$ Standardized values of (KI\_1966S) & & & &      -0.030***&      -0.032***&      -0.029** & & & \\
 & & & &     (0.009)   &     (0.009)   &     (0.012)   & & & \\
      time = 2 $\times$ white $\times$ Standardized values of (F\_s1966) & & & & & & &      -0.038***&      -0.043***&      -0.033***\\
 & & & & & & &     (0.010)   &     (0.011)   &     (0.010)   \\
      &  534,977   &  336,099   &  198,878   &  534,977   &  336,099   &  198,878   &  534,977   &  336,099   &  198,878   \\
  \addlinespace 
  \textbf{L-L elast. (emp. shares)}& 0.01&  0.01&  0.01&   0.02&        0.02&        0.03&        0.02&        0.01&        0.02\\
      se   &              0.01&  0.01&        0.01&        0.02&        0.01&        0.02&        0.01&        0.01&        0.01\\
   lower bound          & 0.00&  0.00&       -0.00&       -0.01&       -0.01&       -0.01&        0.00&        0.00&       -0.01\\
    upper bound         & 0.02&  0.02&        0.03&        0.05&        0.05&        0.06&        0.03&        0.02&        0.04\\
  \addlinespace 
  \textbf{L-L elast. (epop gap)}& 0.10& 0.08& 0.18&       -0.06&        0.01&       -0.21&       -0.08&       -0.05&       -0.07\\
      se   &        0.12&        0.16&        0.25&        0.14&        0.19&        0.17&        0.11&        0.12&        0.24\\
    lower bound         & -0.14&-0.23&       -0.30&       -0.33&       -0.37&       -0.54&       -0.29&       -0.28&       -0.54\\
    upper bound         &  0.34& 0.38&        0.66&        0.22&        0.39&        0.11&        0.14&        0.18&        0.40\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\footnotesize\smallskip
Source: CPS 1962--1981.

Sample: For regressions on (i) share of whites among all workers and (ii)~probability of being employed vs. unemployed or nor in the labor force (in order to look at white-black gap in employment-population ratio): Adults 25--55, black or white, employed, unemployed ((ii)~only) or not in the labor force ((ii)~only). For regression on log annual earnings: Adults 25--55, black or white, worked more than 13 weeks last year and 3 hours last week, not self-employed, not in group quarters, not unpaid family worker, no missing industry or occupation code. 

Notes: see notes of Table~\ref{tab:table_emp_cps_mef}. 

\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks for your professional  answer .. you saved me.. i need to do a robustness  test for our analysis  so i need two keep only two  variables.